# How to specify file specific DEFINES in Qt Creator

Tags: qt, g++, qt-creator

In my current project there is a scenario where UNICODE needs to be defined while compiling most of the files but it has to be specifically not defined to compile two of the files in the project. It might be difficult to place those two files completely in a different folder altogether. Is there anyway to specify such settings in my .pro file?

Answer (score 0):

That's not really supported in QMake.

Only solution I could think of: Create a second .pro file (without the DEFINES in it), in the same directory, in which you link those peculiar files into a static library, then link that static library in the main .pro file (which has the DEFINES). Create a top-level .pro file like this:

```
TEMPLATE = subdirs     
SUBDIRS += staticlib.pro main.pro
CONFIG += ordered
```